# how to "reload" a instance from another instance

Tags: java, sockets, chat

I'm developing a game application client/server. On the client side, in the menubar I put a `jDialog` which can change the connection (ip adress and port) for the server or the user.

Now, when the client presses the "OK" button, I would like to change the real IP address and port of the server (the server is just a little class that I did).

I tried just to recall the constructor but nothing changed. E.g:

```
server = new Server(port);
```

I dont really know where the problem can be. I think maybe once the application started, nothing can be reloaded...

I'm using NetBeans and I use sockets for my client-server connection

Comment: Can you show us some code please?

Comment: And why do you want to change the connection? I'm struggling to see any desirable functionality come from that.

Comment: It is not *generally* the case that "once the application is started, nothing can be reloaded".  If that is the case here, then it's because you wrote your code to make it so.

Comment: well. At first, on my application, i can let the player to decide to change the ipadress of his server and also the port if he wants. but to be able to do that. i need to reload the class server (i think). i tried to change only the port but nothing works.